# Scala project in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have come back to Scala after a while and I currently work on Mac. I have installed Scala 2.13.1 via brew and IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.1.3 is my IDE of choice (of course together with the [Scala plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1347-scala)). I am familiar with how to setup your [Scala project in Intellj](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/) and I am not looking to use sbt, but simply to have a Scala starter project and then use Maven via the *Add Framework Support* option . When I go through the creation of the new project, I am presented with the following:

[image: Create a Scala Project in IntellJ]

I would expect one of the option being simply 'Scala', but it is not there anymore. If I pick Lightbend I can kind make it work (although I need to remove the build.sbt file and add Maven), but if I pick the option called 'IDEA' (IDEA-based Scala project), it simply create a project with the following structure (which is not a Scala project at all):

[image]

I think I am missing something here, can you please help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So, I believe that the quickest solution to this issue is to create a Maven project of the following archetype:

```
<artifactId>scala-archetype-simple</artifactId>
```

That will create a proper scala maven project structure and if the rest is all set up appropriately (e.g. Scala SDK etc), then it will work and compile fine.